# Got Async Function When Convert to base64 AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm a mobile developer and currently I'm developing an hybrid mobile app using angularJS and ionic.

Now I'm getting trouble with async function which have to return value after all conversion and mapping are done, but now I always getting null value because when conversion running it took little bit longer than mapping,

I want to make my mapping running after conversion done.

this is my service

```
angular.module('file.service', ['ionic'])
.factory('fileService', [‘$q’, function($q) {
    var factory = {};

    factory.getContentImageFix = function(fileParsing){
        var contentImg = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < fileParsing.length; i++){
            convertFileToDataURLviaFileReader(fileParsing[i].fullpath, function(base64Img){
                contentImg.push({
                    image: base64Img,
                    width: 400
                });
            });
        }
        return $q.all(contentImg);
    }

    function convertFileToDataURLviaFileReader(url, callback){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.responseType = 'blob';
        xhr.onload = function() {
            var reader  = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function () {
                callback(reader.result);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
        };
        xhr.open('GET', url);
        xhr.send();
    }
}]);
```

and my controller like this

```
angular.module('scan.module’, ['ionic'])
.controller('scanController’, [‘fileService’, function(fileService) {
    var fileParsing = [
        {
            “name”:”a.jpg",
            "fullpath”:”[PATH]/a.jpg"
        },{
            "name”:”b.jpg",
            "fullpath":"[PATH]/b.jpg"
        }
    ];
    var contentImg = fileService.getContentImageFix(fileParsing);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(contentImg)); //not it is return zero array
}]);
```

actually I don't really know about concept of promise, so how do I solve this async problem.

Thanks,

Comment: http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html okay, if you read this, I'll try and see if I can whip up a solution :)

Comment: that was very good explained for knowing promises, now I got the point what are promises, and I think I've to try make promises to convertFile function. Thanks @Pjetr i'll try then.

Comment: Alexander beat me to it, http://plnkr.co/edit/SYLFzkBCwNJAbYzc6dZm?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$q.all() accepts array of promises, so you can change convertFileToDataURLviaFileReader function to return promise, something like this

```
function convertFileToDataURLviaFileReader(url){
    var defer = $q.defer();
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.onload = function() {
        var reader  = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function () {
            defer.resolve(reader.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
    };
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.send();
    return defer.promise;
}
```

then

```
factory.getContentImageFix = function(fileParsing){
    var contentImg = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < fileParsing.length; i++){
          contentImg.push(convertFileToDataURLviaFileReader(fileParsing[i].fullpath));
    }
    return $q.all(contentImg);
}
```

and in controller

```
fileService.getContentImageFix(fileParsing).then(function(contentImg){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(contentImg))
})
```

Comment: thank you so much, it almost work, but I got return value like this [{"image":{"$$state":{"status":0}},"width":400},{"image":{"$$state":{"status":0}},"width":400}] it should be base64 inside image:

Answer (score 0):

since it looks like the accepted answer didn't work:

http://plnkr.co/edit/SXKNbBc2b32UTzYIVsrB?p=preview

```
  FileService.getContentImages(files).then(function(images) {
    $timeout(function() {
      mv.images = images;

      console.log(images);
    }, 0);
  });
```

There was a problem with getting the async data into the current $digest. This was solved using a simple timeout.

Other changes I made was introducing a directive to make it work, because directives are better than controllerAs in divs :)